# ERROR when login to admin section of ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I made ASP.Net website and hosted it into hosting server, I can access to the front end pages however when I want to go to admin section (which allows me to edit database data) and I enter username and password in login page I get error:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

I had tried to delete the web.config file inside the admin folder, then went to admin/default.aspx and then it works, so the error come from the access rules to admin folder,
Can I have some help?

Comment: your connection string (in web.config I assume) isn't connecting to SQL Server, check it.

Comment: Does your front-end use the Database to pull information it is displaying?  If so does it use the same Connection String as the Admin side?

Comment: yes the front end and back end(admin) use the same connection string

Comment: I had tried to delete the web.config file inside the admin folder, then wend to admin/default.aspx, now it works, so the error from the access rules to admin folder, so do you have idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ConnectionStrings in your web.config file. If you developed the site locally, you may be trying to connect to a local instance of your databse such as "DataSource=YOURPCNAME-PC;..."

That should be changed to a public-facing server that you can connect to remotely.

Comment: It is pointed to server, and the front-end shows data properly but I get error whenever I try to login into admin pages

Answer (score 0):

Connectivity problems can be of various flavor.

Try to troubleshoot it systematically, by eliminating the cause:

1. Network issue
2. SQL Server configuration issue
3. Firewall issue
4. Client driver issue
5. Application configuration issue
6. Authentication and logon issue

[Took it from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx), it was a good read.